# SharePoint Workflow Timer job issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

We have created on approval workflow (SharePoint 2010) using SharePoint designer in SharePoint 2013 standard edition environment. The workflow is customized as per below requirement.

We have one custom list in which user will generate the new item and associated workflow generate the task and email. Here we will set the task due date based on configured escalation days like 1 day. After one day if approver is not approved the task then it should escalate to next approver and trigger email/task for the same.

Escalation task logic is implemented in the Task Expire event of Start approval process of workflow.  Now issue is SharePoint workflow timer job is not generating the task and email on time based on task due date. Sometimes it will take long time (more than 10 days where due date is set to 1 day) to generate email and task. This will create critical issue. After some days when we restart the SharePoint timer job service, all items in queue (whose task or email is not generated) is being generated.

Want to know why SharePoint workflow timer job is behaving in such manner. Any solution that SharePoint workflow timer job will run proper and generate escalation task/email on time.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards,

Hitendra

Comment: It would surely be helpful to see any code.

Comment: This is a out of box workflow. we have used Insert task activity to generate task from Task Expire event of workflow.